# MySQL some queries never exectue

Tags: mysql, database, performance, data-science

I am in the middle of my first data science project and I am having some trouble with extremely slow queries using MySQL Workbench.

These are my 3 tables (each of which comes from data sets from various websites that have been cleaned up and inserted into MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `starbucks` (
   `STORE_NUMBER` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `CITY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `STATE` char(2) NOT NULL,
   `ZIPCODE` char(5) NOT NULL,
   `LONG` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `LAT` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`STORE_NUMBER`)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB")

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `income`(
   `STATEFIPS` char(2) NOT NULL,
   `STATE` char(2) NOT NULL,
   `ZIPCODE` char(5) NOT NULL,
   `AGI_STUB` tinyint NOT NULL,
   `NUM_RETURNS` float(15,4) NOT NULL,
   `TOTAL_INCOME` float(15,4) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`STATE`, `ZIPCODE`, `AGI_STUB`)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB")

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `diversity`(
   `COUNTY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `STATE` char(2) NOT NULL,
   `INDEX` float(7,6) NOT NULL,
   `1` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   `2` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   `3` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   `4` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   `5` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   `6` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   `7` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`COUNTY`, `STATE`)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB")
```

`starbucks` has 13,608 records,
`income` has 166,740 records,
`diversity` has 3,143 records.

The query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT  i.TOTAL_INCOME,
    CASE
        WHEN s.STORE_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS has_starbucks
  FROM  income as i
  LEFT  OUTER JOIN starbucks as s
    ON  i.ZIPCODE = s.ZIPCODE
```

If I limit the result to 1,000 rows it will run fast, however I need to get ALL of the records (no row limit) and this is resulting in the query never returning, and eventually timing out and disconnecting me from the MySQL server. 
In the past when working for companies on their databases with MILLIONS of records in them I have never had this much trouble.

What table optimizations do I need to do to fix this? What MySQL settings do I need to change? Any other suggestions welcome.

**EDIT** 
It appears that the 'Duration' of the query never exceeds 0.500 seconds, it is the 'Fetch' part that lasts > 120 seconds. I am not sure if this is useful information.

Comment: You could add STATE as part of the join condition, this is more likely to use the key.

Comment: This doesn't solve your performance issue, but you are going to end up with more than one row per `income` row if there is more than one Starbucks in a Zipcode

Comment: @JenR would `DISTINCT` solve that problem?

Comment: No, you are only returning a Total_Income and a single number - distinct would then reduce any places that have the same total_Income to one row

Comment: There is probably no valid use for `FLOAT(m,n)`; use `INT` for whole numbers, `DECIMAL(m,n)` for money, or plain `FLOAT` for 'scientific' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is create a proper index on join  columns

```
 CREATE INDEX idx1 ON starbucks (ZIPCODE );
 CREATE INDEX idx2 ON income (ZIPCODE );
```

or a verbous index adding the column you select

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON income (ZIPCODE , TOTAL_INCOME);
```

and check the behavior using explain plan

Comment: I did this and a query that used to take 120+ seconds (and sometime never even run successfully) now takes < 0.422 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This won't do much to fix your performance issue but will fix your duplicate row issue -

```
 SELECT  i.TOTAL_INCOME, 1 AS has_starbucks
 FROM  income as i
 WHERE i.Zipcode in (Select zipcode from Starbucks)
   UNION
 SELECT  i.TOTAL_INCOME, 0 AS has_starbucks
 FROM  income as i
 WHERE i.Zipcode not in (Select zipcode from Starbucks)
```

EXISTS is sometimes more efficient than IN

```
 SELECT  i.TOTAL_INCOME, 1 AS has_starbucks
 FROM  income as i
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (   SELECT 1 
     FROM Starbucks s
     WHERE s.zipcode = i.Zipcode
 )
   UNION
 SELECT  i.TOTAL_INCOME, 0 AS has_starbucks
 FROM  income as i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (   SELECT 1 
     FROM Starbucks s
     WHERE s.zipcode = i.Zipcode
 )
```

Comment: I figured out it was the `SUM(TOTAL_INCOME)` that I needed for each `ZIPCODE`, where each `ZIPCODE` has 6 different total_income's based on the `AGI_STUB`, so I used `SUM(i.TOTAL_INCOME)` and `GROUP BY i.ZIPCODE` in my original query. However both of our queries did not return due to `...Lost connection to MySQL server during query`